# Cómo mostrar SOLO el país del usuario en el dropdown de País/Región del checkout de WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**Lo que NO estoy tratando de hacer:**

- Eliminar u ocultar los campos de país (billing/shipping) en el checkout.

**Lo que SÍ estoy tratando de hacer:**

- Mostrar un ÚNICO país en el selector de País/Región del checkout (billing/shipping), dependiendo de la geolocalización del usuario (la geolocalización ya está hecha)
- O, Eliminar los países (options) que no quiero mostrar al usuario en el selector de País/Región del checkout

**Hechos:**

- Lista "Vender a países específicos": Alemania, Andorra, Austria, Bulgaria, Bélgica, Croacia, Dinamarca, Eslovaquia, Eslovenia, España, Estonia, Finlandia, Francia, Grecia, Hungría, Irlanda, Letonia, Lituania, Luxemburgo, Mónaco, Países Bajos, Polonia, Portugal, Reino Unido (UK), República Checa, Rumanía, Suecia y Suiza.
- Quiero vender a todos estos países, por lo que eliminar países de la lista de ubicaciones de venta no es una solución.
- Necesito una solución tipo hook/filter, por favor.

**Lo que he hecho hasta ahora:**

- He probado varios hooks/filters para conseguirlo: `woocommerce_checkout_get_value`, `woocommerce_shipping_fields`, `woocommerce_billing_fields`, `woocommerce_default_address_fields` y `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. Ninguno parece que funcione...

**Código que he escrito:**

```
// NO FUNCIONA! MUESTRA TODOS LOS PAÍSES DE LA LISTA "Vender a países específicos"
function override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'] = array(
        'type'         => 'country',
        'label'        => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'country',
        'priority'     => 40,
        'options'      => array( $user_country_code => __( $user_country_name, 'woocommerce' ) )
    );
    
    //Lo mismo para billing_country...
    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );

// NO FUNCIONA! MUESTRA TODOS LOS PAÍSES DE LA LISTA "Vender a países específicos"
function edit_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_country'] = array(
        'type'         => 'country',
        'label'        => __( 'Country / Region', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'     => true,
        'class'        => array( 'form-row-wide', 'address-field', 'update_totals_on_change' ),
        'autocomplete' => 'country',
        'priority'     => 40,
        'options'      => array( $user_country_code => __( $user_country_name, 'woocommerce' ) )
    );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'edit_billing_fields' );

... Y más
```

**NOTA:** Si cambio `'type' => 'country'` por `'type' => 'select'` entonces funciona, pero si cambio de país (fuerzo que se muestren dos países), el dropdown de 'Provincia' no se actualiza con las provincias/estados para el país que acabo de seleccionar. Además, el dropdown se muestra sin la apariencia Select2.

**Explicación adicional:**
Ahora mismo vendo a 28 países. Por ejemplo, si un usuario accede a la web desde Francia, cuando el usuario llega al formulario de finaliza compra, solo quiero permitirle enviar el producto a Francia. Esta es la razón por la que quiero mostrar solo el país del usuario (previamente geolocalizado) en el menú desplegable del país (billing_country/shipping_country).

Gracias de antemano! Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo atacando a un filtro distinto, uno que no tiene que ver con el *checkout* directamente. El filtro en cuestión es `woocommerce_countries_allowed_countries`. Este filtro está en la función `get_allowed_countries()` y obtiene los países a los que vende la tienda. Así que limitando los países a los que vende la tienda, soluciono el problema del listado de países en el *checkout*.

```
/**
 * @param array $countries
 * @return array
 */
function custom_update_allowed_countries( $countries ) {

    // Solo en *frontend*
    if( is_admin() ) return $countries;

    if( class_exists( 'WC_Geolocation' ) ) {
        $location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();

        if ( isset( $location['country'] ) ) {
            $countryCode = $location['country'];
        } else {
            // Si no hay un país, devuelvo los países permitidos
            return $countries;
        }
    } else {
        // Si no puede geolocalizar el país de usuario por IP, devuelvo los países permitidos
        return $countries;
    }

    // Si todo salió bien, entonces filtro el país del usuario en el array de países permitidos
    $user_country_code_array = array( $countryCode );

    $intersect_countries = array_intersect_key( $countries, array_flip( $user_country_code_array ) );

    return $intersect_countries;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_allowed_countries', 'custom_update_allowed_countries', 30, 1 );
```

Comment: Lo he probado porque necesito lo mismo y me da error en: $user_country_code_array = array( countryCode ); Alguna ayuda para solucionarlo?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia! Me he olvidado de añadir el dolar ($) delante de countryCode. Edito la respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

probá con

```php
function SOes366545_woo_set_only_one_country( $countries ) 
{
   $countries = array( $user_country_code => __( $user_country_name, 'woocommerce' ) );
   return $countries; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'SOes366545_woo_set_only_one_country', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Hola @aloMalbarez! Gracias por tu respuesta. Tu propuesta me ha abierto los ojos! Tu código no me ha funcionado del todo, pero me ha servido para buscar ese filtro y encontrar otro con el que sí que ha funcionado, así que te agradezco la aportación! El filtro que he usado es este `woocommerce_countries_allowed_countries`.